# Windows 7 Default Audio Device Problems, PJLIB VOIP SDK

Tags: windows-7, voip, sip, pjsip

I have been able to build [PJSUA](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsua.htm). The softphone runs perfectly on Windows XP, but on Windows 7 but it gives me the following error

[image: Error Message]
It seems to be an issue with PJSUA on Windows 7. Has anyone been able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the code you will see that PJSUA is looking for a default device that has both input and output (mic and speakers) - such as headset. Just output or just input will not work...So if you plug in a headset you may eliminate your error. It works great on Win7.

The audio part of PJSIP is quite complicated IMO. Although I have it working now I am myself researching how to implement giving user a choice. That is, the user will have a choice of using headset or mic/speakers built-in combo.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is incompatible with windows7, and so is `Sipek`, because of some library which is no longer present in Windows7 (`libwavemixer`, ...).
I went on to use the Java-based **[Peers SIP Phone](http://peers.sourceforge.net/)**.

Comment: This was a long time ago. I did not have the directx sdk installed though. Does it provide libwavemixer? I think I ran into an issue where it was no longer a part of windows, but attaching a headset did work as far as I remember.